# How to avoid 100% CPU on CREATE INDEX

Tags: postgresql, index

I'm indexing a partitioned table with about 200 million rows, each row is ~1kb in size.
I run multiple CREATE INDEX statements sequentially and its pegging the CPU at 100% for 2 hours. Is there a way i can make this less CPU intensive ?

It is worth noting i have increased `maintenance_work_mem` to **~2GB** before executing, so that might've invited more parallelism ?

`SHOW max_parallel_maintenance_workers;` returns `2`

I'm running an *db.m6g.large* with 2 vCPUs and 8GB memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *reduce* the CPU consumption of `CREATE INDEX`, the most effective way is to disable parallel query by setting `max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 0`. Then `CREATE INDEX` will only use a single CPU core.

To reduce the time that `CREATE INDEX` takes to build an index (and so to reduce the time during which it consumes CPU), you can allot more memory to it by raising `maintenance_work_mem`.